# How do I delete a string object element stored in Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, graphql

I am trying to delete an entire object stored in Redis using LREM, but I don't think I am doing it right, below is the code I tried:

GraphQL mutation:

deleteImage: async(_,args) => {

```
    let data = await client.lrem("postedImagesList",0,JSON.stringify(args.id));
    return data
  }
```

postedImagesList is a redis collection of all the object elements stringified:

```
1) "{\"id\":\"aadc8456-a5c9-46b9-a58c-670446d95c70\",\"url\":\"chas\",\"description\":\"asd\",\"posterName\":\"asda\",\"binned\":false,\"userPosted\":true}"
 2) "{\"id\":\"a24d6d1b-224f-400d-8b84-dac83d8eaf92\",\"url\":\"ihir\",\"description\":\"helped\",\"posterName\":\"bhi\",\"binned\":false,\"userPosted\":true}"
```

I am given the id as an argument and I have to delete the entire object, how can I do so? I am adding the elements using lpushasync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [LREM](https://redis.io/commands/lrem/) docs.

```
 LREM key count element
```

The `element` argument has to have an exact match, so you can't match by ID.

You might want to consider using the [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/) using the [JSON.DEL](https://redis.io/commands/json.del/) you should be easily achieve what you're looking for.